# req.file is undefined using multer with upload.array to upload an image

Tags: node.js, express, upload, multer

Can someone please tell me what's wrong in my below code? I've been debugging this for hours but no luck.

```
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: '/uploads/' })
router.post('/image', upload.array('file', 12) , function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body, req.file);
  // I got this here {} undefined

});
```

cilent

```
<form method="post" action="/products/image" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Comment: If you use `upload.array` I guess that only `req.files` (and **not** `req.file`) is defined. Change `req.file` to `req.files` to see if it outputs something. If you solve your problem, please share the answer with us, because it could be useful for visitor users with your same or similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that on the server you use `/image` but on the client `/products/image`. It could be the problem, if not - please share all your server source code.

Answer (score 0):

try to use req.files with 's',  instead of req.file